# Canvas Draw Text is not showing text on real device/emulator

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawtext

I have used canvas.drawText("1"....), but it shows differently on real device and emulator. Layout Editor shows '1' correctly [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxkTI.png)

But on device/emulator it shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNkAA.png)

I tried disabling hardware acceleration in manifest file but it doesn't work.

I also tried "text" string, same thing happened [layout editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omXmp.png)  / [device&emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki0BU.png)

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find the solution, I was using Paint.Style.STROKE, I changed it to fill with paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); and it solved my problem